# Get each page of an object Page - Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, pagination

I need to scroll through the pages of my page object and make that page in a list, the problem is that I can not iterate my page object, this is the return method:

```
return new PageImpl(myList, pageable,count);
```

And this is how I'm trying to manipulate it:

```
 Page page = StuffManager.getAllthings(con,PageRequest.of(4, 260));

   while (page.hasPrevious()){
      List<ThingsDto> pagedThings= page.getContent();
```

How to switch to the previous page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [`Page#previousPageable`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html#previousPageable--) in your `while` loop.

```
while(pageData.hasPrevious() && !pageData.isFirst()){
     pageData = myRepo.findAll(pageData.previousPageable());
     List<ThingsDto> pagedThings = pageData.getContent();
     ...
}
```